# How to display jquery ui accordion and drupal 7

Tags: views, javascript

the jqueryui accordion it only takes the first item from the list. I copy into my theme views-view-field--field-summary.tpl.php file and add this code

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--<title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <?php print '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>';?>
  <?php print '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>';?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />




<?php print '<div id="accordion">';?>
     <?php print '<h3>Show summary</h3>'; ?>
         <?php print '<div>'; ?>
           <?php print '<p>'; ?>
             <?php print $output; ?>
           <?php print '</p>'; ?> 
        <?php print '</div>'; ?>
   <?php print '</div>'; ?>


   <?php print '<script>
  $(function() {

$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
  });
  </script>';?>
```

The output is what you show in the picture.[image: example]
Why remaining elements take no accordion effect?

Comment: There is already module https://drupal.org/project/views_accordion to integrate accordion with views.

Comment: I do not want to use views_accordion, I do it this way.

Comment: Then you need to embed your javascript in code `(function($) { [accordion code] })(jQuery);`